# .json adds double inverted commas

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write Python code which sorts images by extension and categorizes them to a .json file. When printing the string the syntax matches the standard `{'key1' : 'value1'}`. However, when opening the `.json` file, I notice it adds double inverted commas like `"{'key1' : 'value1'}"`
I'm not sure what is causing this to happen, here's my code:

```
for i in range(0,jpgCounter,1):  
    jpgBufferConfig =  '\''+str(i)+'\'' + ' : '  +'\''+ str(jpgList[i]) +'\'' 
    jpgConfig = jpgConfig + jpgBufferConfig+ " , " 
jpgConfig = jpgConfig[:-3]
jpgConfig = '{' + jpgConfig + '}' 

print jpgConfig 

with open ('config.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(jpgConfig,f)
```

Comment: Those are *double quotes*, not inverted commas.

Comment: You should pass a dictionary to json.dump. It looks like you have make a json string already. In that case json.dump will only make sure that the string is valid json by wrapping it with double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this. You are creating a *string*, then encode that string to JSON; `json.dump()` takes Python objects, and translates those to a JSON object. That that string contains single quote, comma and curly brace characters doesn't matter, those are part of the string value encoded. You essentially double-encoded the data.

Create a Python dictionary, and encode *that* to JSON:

```
jpgConfig = {str(i): str(item) for i, item in enumerate(jpgList)}
print jpgConfig   # prints the Python object produced as Python syntax.

with open ('config.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(jpgConfig, f)
```

Apart from double-encoding, you were actually producing invalid JSON (using single quotes instead of double). You'll notice that the JSON produced will look like:

```
{"key1": "value1"}
```